# Braintree js/php full working example working like Paypal Express Checkout?

Tags: php, paypal, braintree

I'm trying to understand if it's convenient for a client to switch from Paypal Express Checkout to Braintree, but I find the latter way too complicated and hard to understand (terrible docs, only reference is good).

Documentation lacks COMPLETE WORKING examples, with all the pages needed where you can just change API credentials and everything works. That is fundamental for any system/API to get quickly the logic and workflow.

I basically currently have a checkout system with all my customer's data and a basket_id, with a form a redirect customer to Paypal passing all these data, and once the customer completes the payment Paypal calls back a URL on my server sending back all the data I sent plus transaction id, and this way I mark that basket_id/order as paid and assign to it a transaction. And no sensitive payment data are typed or pass through our server/network.

How to do all this on Braintree js+php? Any full and complete sandbox working example where I can just change my credentials and have working code to understand the logics? Is much faster than reading the honestly quite confusing documentation.

Thanks!